# Isset em ternário PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho os seguintes exemplos de condição em ternario, no primeiro exemplo ele funciona corretamente, ele me retorna o dados e se estiver vazio retorna `null`, 
 porem no segundo exemplo que eu acho que seria o correto, ele me retorna os dados corretamente mais não me retorna `null` quando vazio.

Exemplo 1:

```
$data->mala_grande = ($t->malagrande) ? $t->malagrande :null;
```

Exemplo 2

```
$data->mala_grande = (isset($t->malagrande)) ? $t->malagrande :null;
```

- Estaria fazendo algo de errado utilizando esse primeiro exemplo sem o `isset`?
- Posso continuar nessa opção?
- A primeira opção Sem colocar o `isset` ela estaria fazendo o mesmo papel automaticamente?

Comment: `isset()` não é pra testar se está vazio. `empty()` é para testar se está vazio.

Comment: o o problema é que com empty() ocorre a mesma coisa

Comment: Complementei a resposta e pus mais um exemplo. Espero que atenda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isset()` não é serve para testar se um valor é vazio. A função é verificar se a variável está definida ou não.

O `empty()` é para testar se uma variável é "vazia", e tem a mesma propriedade do `isset` de não gerar um *warning* se a variável for inexistente:

```
$data->mala_grande = ! empty($t->malagrande) ? $t->malagrande : null;
//                   ^ o ! inverte a lógica do teste
```

Ou ainda

```
$data->mala_grande = empty($t->malagrande) ? null : $t->malagrande;
```

No primeiro caso estamos usando o *not empty* (`! empty()`), ou seja:

- "se **não** for vazio retorna `t->malagrande`, do contrário `null`.

No segundo caso:

- "se for vazio retorna null, do contrário, `t->malagrande`.

Resultam na mesma coisa, escritas de maneiras diferentes.

Manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php

Comment: o o problema é que com empty ocorre a mesma coisa

Comment: @FabioHenrique sem o empty, se `$t` for `null`, não for um objeto, ou for um objeto mas não tiver essa propriedade `malagrande`, vai dar um erro. A verificação com `empty` previne isso. Seria essa a dúvida?

Comment: Mais Me tira uma duvida porque no primeiro exemplo funciona corretamente, quando não coloco nem insert nem empty

Comment: Nâo funciona corretamente, ele gera um warning. O que pode acontecer é você não estar olhando o log de erros entao ele aparentemente está ok (mas o warning acontece e vai para um arquivo de log se estiver tudo configurado corretamente).